# Read multiple NDEF with windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, ndef

I'm very new to windows phone 8 development and i'm on my way developing a application which uses several NFC tags. I have around 10-20 tags which has NDEF messages with multiples records written to them. By using a custom URI scheme i'm able to open the application as soon as my nfc tag hits the reader but here is my doubt.

Windows phone always requests for confirmation upon each nfc connection. I want to avoid this since i can't do this for the entire 20 nfc tags. Is their any possibility that i can create a connection between the nfc tags and the application just by pairing it once. I can always keep a NDEF record with a **custom URI Scheme** in all the 20 tags so no matter what tag is read., the app is triggered.

**peerfinder** is my only hope but i can't exactly figure out how to accept communication from all the 20 tags or in other words to establish a long term connection with all the tags from a random tag selected. Can you please be kind to suggest me a good approach for this. A code example would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/mopius/nfc-in-practice-creating-cross-platform-nfc-solutions-for-android-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8?slide=43), Windows will always show this confirmation dialog for known NDEF record types, even if your app is registered for that type and is in the foreground. Seems you can't diable this behavior with the current API.

Comment: But after you establish a long term  connection, this should avoid it but im stuck at creating the specific connection

Comment: If you refer to peerfinder, that's for "pairing" between apps on multiple devices and not between apps and NFC tags.